# Why VetList method of Vets class in PetClinic sample is using XMLElement?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am studying PetClinic sample of Spring MVC.

1) I am not sure when is [Vets class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/model/Vets.java) called? Answered in comments , link to location of the class that [call it](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/web/VetController.java).

2) Is that used by [vetList.jsp](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/vets/vetList.jsp)?

3) Why is it returning XML?

**Vets.java**

```
package org.springframework.samples.petclinic.model;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
/**
* Simple domain object representing a list of veterinarians. Mostly here to be used for the 'vets' {@link
* org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView}.
*
* @author Arjen Poutsma
*/
@XmlRootElement
public class Vets {
    private List<Vet> vets;

    @XmlElement
    public List<Vet> getVetList() {
       if (vets == null) {
              vets = new ArrayList<Vet>();
       }
       return vets;
     }
}
```

Comment: It says right there that it's a simple domain class and where it's primarily used.

Comment: @chrylis I read that buddy, but do not get it why do we have just one domain object and not for other ones such as ownerslist? When is this class called?

Comment: Did you look at the class linked to in the comment? I'm pretty sure that in this case "domain object" means the same thing as DTO, which should have a number of good articles.

Comment: @chrylis I guess so but when is it called? why there is no such a thing for owenerslist? Why is this the only class that is returning XML?

Comment: It is used in VetController  -> https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/web/VetController.java

Comment: @apurvc thanks for your comment, do you have any answers for my other questions as well?

Comment: @Jack xmlelement is jaxb annotation. JAXB is specification to convert java objects to xml and vice-verse.   As Spring mvc allows different response object based on accept headers a consumer requesting xml type can get xml and one needing json can get json response.

Comment: @apurvc thanks for your comment, I know JAXB and that annotation, my kind question is that why this output is the only one that is returning xml is there any specific reason?  Also is that used by vetList.jsp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats just to demonstrate a xml response no specific reason. I think it is used here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="datatables" uri="http://github.com/dandelion/datatables" %>

<html lang="en">


<jsp:include page="../fragments/staticFiles.jsp"/>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <jsp:include page="../fragments/bodyHeader.jsp"/>

    <h2>Veterinarians</h2>

    <datatables:table id="vets" data="${vets.vetList}" row="vet" theme="bootstrap2" cssClass="table table-striped" pageable="false" info="false">
        <datatables:column title="Name">
            <c:out value="${vet.firstName} ${vet.lastName}"></c:out>
        </datatables:column>
        <datatables:column title="Specialties">
            <c:forEach var="specialty" items="${vet.specialties}">
                <c:out value="${specialty.name}"/>
            </c:forEach>
            <c:if test="${vet.nrOfSpecialties == 0}">none</c:if>
        </datatables:column>
    </datatables:table>

    <table class="table-buttons">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="<spring:url value="/vets.xml" htmlEscape="true" />">View as XML</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="<spring:url value="/vets.atom" htmlEscape="true" />">Subscribe to Atom feed</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <jsp:include page="../fragments/footer.jsp"/>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```